# Postgresql get total matches by player

Tags: postgresql, aggregation

I've got the following Postgres query:

```
SELECT p_id as player_id, name as player_name
FROM Players
LEFT OUTER JOIN matches
ON Players.p_id = matches.player1 or Players.p_id = matches.player2
;
```

and it returns the following

```
 player_id |    player_name
-----------+-------------------
         1 | Twilight Sparkle
         1 | Twilight Sparkle
         2 | Fluttershy
         3 | Applejack
         3 | Applejack
         4 | Pinkie Pie
         5 | "Rarity
         5 | "Rarity
         6 | Rainbow Dash
         7 | Princess Celestia
         7 | Princess Celestia
         8 | Princess Luna
```

How can I end up with a table of unique p_id's with each one's name and the total of rows that p_id is in?

```
player_id |    player_name     |  total_matches
-----------+-------------------+------
         1 | Twilight Sparkle  | 2
         2 | Fluttershy        | 1
         3 | Applejack         | 1
         4 | Pinkie Pie        | 1
         5 | "Rarity           | 2
         6 | Rainbow Dash      | 1
         7 | Princess Celestia | 2
         8 | Princess Luna     | 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using the group clause:

```
SELECT p_id as player_id, name as player_name, count(*) as total_matches
FROM Players
LEFT OUTER JOIN matches
ON Players.p_id = matches.player1 or Players.p_id = matches.player2
GROUP BY name
;
```

Comment: That will throw an error. You need `group by player_id` (assuming `player_id` is the primary key)

Comment: @JosephPerez `group by 1, 2`